# element not rendering even if null

Tags: apex, visualforce, html

So I'm runining into an issue. the border around the field doesn't render if the field's value  is null.  When there is a value, it renders fine.. What's going on? what i want is an empty box if the value is null

```
<style>
.field {color: #003366; width: 140px; }
table {background-color: #f1f2e9; width: 100%;}
td.header {word-wrap:break-word; text-align: left; font-weight:bold; vertical-align:bottom;}
td.data {text-align: left; border: .2em solid #dedbc5; padding: 3px;}
body {background-color: #f1f2e9;}

</style>



<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Known Opportunities"/>
<body>
<table class="basic">
  <tr>    
    <td class="header" width="220px">Opportunity Name</td>
    <td class="header" width="100px">Num of People</td>
  </tr>

  <apex:repeat value="{!allOpps}" var="opps">
    <tr>
        <td class="data"><a href="/{!opps.Id}" target="_new"><apex:outputText value="{!opps.Name}" /></a></td>
        <td class="data"><apex:outputText value="{0,number}"><apex:param value="{!opps.no_of_people__c}" /></apex:outputText></td>      
    </tr>        
  </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an image of what it currently looks like to better describe the problem?

Comment: updated. Sadly, I can't upload a screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML does this by default; cells that are completely empty do not render a border. Add a zero-width space (&#8203;) at the end of the cell to add whitespace that will cause the cell to render its border.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!allOpps}" var="opps">
    <tr>
        <td class="data"><a href="/{!opps.Id}" target="_new"><apex:outputText value="{!opps.Name}" /></a>&#8203;</td>
        <td class="data"><apex:outputText value="{0,number}"><apex:param value="{!opps.no_of_people__c}" />&#8203;</apex:outputText></td>      
    </tr>        
  </apex:repeat>
```